# How to grab JSON values with Ajax JQuery.each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, loops

this is my first question here! New to using Ajax, and have hit an issue that maybe someone could catch what I am doing wrong.

```
    var featuredList;
    $.ajax({
        url: "myurl",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result){
            featuredList = JSON.stringify(result);

            alert(result);

            $.each( result, function( key, value ) {
                alert('not working');
            });
        },
                error: function(){alert('error');}
    });
```

I have gone this path before with no issues, this time around I cannot get inside the loop. The alert(result) is returning my data just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `JSON.stringify` line. jQuery hase already deserialised the response for you, there is no need to turn it back in to a string again.

Comment: If it really is JSON, it's a string, and `$.each` won't do much, and as there is no dataType set, that's a posibility.

Comment: It might be worth looking at $.map as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code try doing this:it should work

```
var data = JSON.parse(result);//here result should be json encoded data
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
            alert(value);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hi**,

Hope this might help you to **process JSON data received from AJAX request, try below code:**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'myurl',
    dataType: "json",
    data:{
        classId:'C001'
    },
    type: "GET",

    success: function(data) {
        for (var j=0; j < data.length; j++) {

            //syntax to get value for given key
            //data[j].yourKey

            var userId = data[j].userId;  
            var name = data[j].name;
            var address = data[j].address;
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks,

~Chandan

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery promises, gives you more semantic and readable code

```
var featuredList;
$.getJSON("myurl", {"optional": "data"})
    .done(function(data){
        // successful ajax query
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
            // do whatever you want with your iterated data.
        });
    });
    .fail(function(){
        // catch errors on ajax query
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way

```
$.getJSON('url',                       
    function(dataList) {   // on server side I do the json_encode of the response data 
        if(dataList !== null) {
            $.each(dataList, function(index, objList ) {
                // rest of code here 
            });
        }
 });
```

Hope this works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getArray(){
    return $.getJSON('url');
}
var gdata = [];


getArray().then(function(json) {

    $.each(json, function(key, val) {
        gdata[key] =  val ;
    });

    console.log(gdata);
```

I had the Same Problem It took 2 days to got the solution.
You have to resolve the promise and return the json object to access the value.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this using the open source project http://www.jinqJs.com

```
/* For Async Call */
var result = null;
jinqJs().from('http://.....', function(self){
  result = self.select();
});

/* For Sync Call */
var result = jinqJs().from('http://....').select();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use $.Json to get your solution , here is an example

```js
 $.getJSON('questions.json', function (data) {
   
   $.each(data,function(index,item){
     
      console.log(item.yourItem); // here you can get your data
     
     }
   
   }
```

You can use or print Index if you want it. Its show the data index.

Hope it may help you, I am exactly not sure its your requirement or not, But i have tried my best to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

This will work as the result from ajax call is a string.

```
$.each($.parseJSON(result), function( key, value ) {
   alert('This will work');
});
```